# Ruby - API RestClient - JSON

Tags: ruby, json, api, rest, automated-tests

Just getting started with API testing and struggling, used to just doing front end selenium web-driver tests, however, I need to get my head around API testing.

I kind of understand the basics such as Get will get the data from the url and post will post data to the url, I think that is correct, however, I could be wrong.

The issue I am having is below:

```
 response = RestClient.post 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',

  {:title => 'mr', :first_name => 'bob', :second_name => 'smith'}

    data1 = JSON.parse(response)

        p data1
```

So I am assigning the restclient.post to the response variable and posting the hash key, value pairs to the url? Then I am using JSON to parse the response and then printing the response to the console. What I need to do is extract each value from the hash and print each value to the console so it shows the data as mr bob smith. Instead of {:title => 'mr', :first_name => 'bob', :second_name => 'smith'}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print "#{ data1[ :title ]} #{data1[:first_name]} #{data1[:second_name]}"
```

Comment: Can you explain this? I understand that data1 is the variable and between the square brackets that they are the keys in the hash, however, can you explain how this prints the values of the keys and not the keys themselves?

Comment: Sure. When you use `"#{ foo }"` foo is evaluated. In this case, we are accessing the value of the key: `data1[:title]`.

Comment: Thanks, Would this be the best way to do what I needed or could you iterate through the hash and then print each value that way? Would like so work? data1.each do |i| p i['title']['first_name']['second_name'] end

Comment: Haha, I thought the same thing. It doesn't make sense to iterate over the keys because a hash does not have an order. It might make sense to put the use a method to wrap up the string.

Comment: By way this was the wrong answer but I figured it out, I will change code so edit is correct.